# bulk insertions with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am wondering whether we can perform bulk insertion using a method like:
`DBSession.bulk_save_objects` mentioned [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/performance.html)

But with ignoring integrity errors related to duplicate keys.
Meaning, we will insert all the new records into DB and duplicates keys will be ignored

Comment: No, integrity check on the database server not ignored with `bulk_save_objects`.

Comment: Create a temporary table, bulk save there, insert from said temporary table using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE <some dummy update op, pk = pk seems common>. Or just insert directly, using Core, with ON DUPLICATE ...

Comment: @IljaEverilä: I'm not sure I got you right, can please explain more?

Comment: Wrote that in haste... I mean you should use the MySQL specific [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#insert-on-duplicate-key-update-upsert) statement, which SQLAlchemy supports through [`mysql.dml.insert()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.dml.insert). That way you can insert, while "ignoring" duplicate keys. Just perform some dummy UPDATE on duplicates, such as `UPDATE id=id` or some such. In order to provide you a proper answer, please produce a [mcve].